# Handling multiple UISwitches with a single IBAction method

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I have the following IBAction that is linked to several switch in my application.  I would like to figure out which switch is clicked.  Each UISwitch has a specific name.  I want that name.

```
- (IBAction)valueChanged:(UISwitch *)theSwitch { //Get name of switch and do something... }
```

Comment: Define "name of the switch" please.

Answer (score 2):

The IBAction passes a pointer to the switch that performed the action. You can get any property off of it.

To compare switches:

```
- (void)valueChanged:(UISwitch *)theSwitch {

    if ([theSwitch isEqual:self.switch1]) {
        NSLog(@"The first switch was toggled!");
    }
    else if ([theSwitch isEqual:self.switch2]) {
        NSLog(@"The second switch was toggled!");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Some other switch was toggled!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more about this please?

Comment: The parameter that's passed to the method, `(UISwitch *)theSwitch` is the actual switch that was touched. You can determine which one was touched and base your action on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use tags:

When you create the switches you need to set their tags.

```
- (IBAction)valueChanged:(UISwitch *)theSwitch { 
    switch(theSwitch.tag){
        case 0:
        {
            //things to be done when the switch with tag 0 changes value
        }
        break;
        case 1:
        {
            //things to be done when the switch with tag 0 changes value
        }
        break;
        // ...
        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Or check if the switch is one of your controller properties

```
- (IBAction)valueChanged:(UISwitch *)theSwitch { 
    if(theSwitch == self.switch1){
        //things to be done when the switch1 changes value
    } else if (theSwitch == self.switch2) {
        //things to be done when the switch2 changes value
    }// test all the cases you have
}
```

Comment: I like this second approach but I am getting an error.  Implicit conversion of int to uiswitch is disallowed with ARC.

Comment: `self.switch1` is supposed to be the `IBOutlet` for your switch, not the value of the switch.

Answer (score 0):

I don't thank you can get the name of that switch. You could tag each of the switches, and use that tag to determine the name of the switch.

Answer (score 0):

UISwitch doesn't have a name property.  But you can subclass it and add a name property to the subclass.  Then create switches from the subclass instead of UISwitch and give them a name when you init them.

```
@class MySwitch : UISwitch
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
@end
```

Then the event handler can access them name string:

```
- (IBAction)valueChanged:(MySwitch *)theSwitch { 
    NSLog(@"switch %@ value changed", theSwitch.name);
}
```

But I think the better answer is to use the tag field already there and use integer tags to identify the switches rather than a string.  You can create enumeration constants in your code to name the tag values:

```
enum { SomeSwitch = 1, AnotherSwitch = 2, MainSwitch = 3 } _SwitchTags;
```

The best answer is the one @Moxy mentioned to compare the switch's pointer to your controller's properties to figure out which switch changed.  That's what I do in my code.  Tags and names are too error prone in the long run.